# Magento 2 - payment available via API (REST, graphql) but not visible on website

Tags: magento, magento2, payment, payment-method

Could somebody tell me if this is possible in Magento 2 - to have payment method I can choose via API (programmatically) but not show (this payment method) on store website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, as long as the method is enabled, you can extend your front template to filter only the method you want. But all the methods that you need either in front or in API have to be enabled. After that, it's just your decision with the template.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I was finding some info on magentostackexchange:
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/273842/disabling-payment-method-for-frontend-but-not-api
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/124545/make-payment-method-active-only-for-api?rq=1
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/277480/not-rendering-specific-payment-method-in-template?rq=1
Maybe somebody need it. Thanks!